# Элементы сайта появляются поверх фиксированного блока

Tags: html, css

Зафиксировал header и стал наблюдать следующую проблему: некоторые объекты при скроллинге появляются на фиксированном объекте.

```
<div id="top_head" style="width: 100%; position: fixed; top: 0;">
<h4 class="c-white">
<span class="icon fa-heartbeat"></span> Site <span class="icon fa-heartbeat">
</h4>
</div>
```

Старт:

[image]

Далее:

[image]

Ещё:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Задайте для шапки свойство `z-index` - оно должно быть больше, чем у всех объектов, которые сейчас над вашей шапкой (например, больше, чем у блока Recaptcha).

Стили:

```
.header {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 1000;
}
```

И, соответственно, верстка:

```
<div class="header" id="top_head">
  <h4 class="c-white">
    <span class="icon fa-heartbeat"></span> Site <span class="icon fa-heartbeat"></span>
  </h4>
</div>
```